# start prog1.exe , wait until full starts fully then start prog2.exe

Tags: c#, process

My prog1.exe starts with this code. My purpose is to start another prog2.exe after the first one fully started. By the way, the first program takes about 2 minutes to start, then I need Prog2.exe to start after. Any help?.

```
{
    Process pProcess = new Process();
    pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Programs\Prog1.exe";
    pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    pProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
    pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    pProcess.Start();
}
```

My process is a simens station configurator which runs on winxp32, it takes about 2 minutes to load all components and appears in taskbar, then I have to start the main application. If I make them autostart with windows I receive conflict error file.db which is used by both, but if I start the station manager first and wait until it fully started and visible on taskbar then start the main application, no errors and working fine.

I was considering using `Thread.Sleep` but the problem that the first application has no exact time to start, sometimes it takes 2 min other more or less.

Comment: do you have a file that you can put a watch on for a lock or a time modified change?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of process you are running `pProcess.WaitForInputIdle()` you will have a running process.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforinputidle?view=netframework-4.8